# Transfer cursor from one JTextField to another on Enter press?

Tags: java, swing, focus, awt, focusmanager

I have one `JTextField` called Name and one `JTextArea` called Address. My requirement is when user has entered name in the `JTextField`and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> key the cursor should go to the next text area which is Address.

Currently one can move from one textfield to other by pressing the tab key (which I believe is default). I would like to prohibit this and transfer the cursor only via the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

I have tried `transferfocus()`, but enter key does not take the cursor to the text area. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `RequestFocus()'?

Comment: Show us your code for capturing and acting upon an ENTER key press.

Answer (score 2):

> My requirement is when user has entered name in the JTextFieldand pressed enter key the cursor should go to the next text area which is Address.

Assuming the components follow one another in the normal tabbing order you can write general code:

```
Action enterAction = new AbstractAction()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        manager.getFocusOwner().transferFocus();
    }
}

...

textField.addActionListener( enterAction );
```

> Currently one can move from one textfield to other by pressing the tab key (which I believe is default). I would like to prohibit this and transfer the cursor only via the ENTER key.

Why do you want to prohibit this. As you say tab is the default so most user will be familiar with this approach. Don't reinvent a UI and give the users a choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think You use Swing..Sorry for Late Reply..

JTextField -> right click -> goto key press event

```
private void NameKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        int a = evt.getKeyCode();
        if (a == 10) {                     // for enter key
          Address.requestFocus();
        } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@satya's answer is right, however a slight alteration to avoid magic numbers is:

```
private void jTextFieldItmCodeKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                             
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
       Address.requestFocus();
    }   
}
```